# Allow short videos for users to demo their system

Tags: discussion, feature-request, android-app

Would it be better if Stack Overflow allowed users to provide a short video to demo how their system works and what the errors they face? This would be easier to understand since some of the users may not be good with English. I came across with this problem and sometimes need to attach a lot of pictures in order to get my problem solved. So I strongly suggest that Stack Overflow provide such a feature.

What do you guys think?

I'm not referring to either pictures of code or video. What I meant is sight, a short video which can provide a length maybe not more than 20 seconds, so that it can be easily to understand by all the readers. Of course, the user has to type their own code instead of giving a picture of code.

Comment: You can already post pictures...but if you're posting pictures of code, there's no value in that since pictures' text isn't indexed by any search engine.

Comment: But sometimes it may need a lot of pictures and thus make the post longer. Maybe user can demo their system and problem by using sight instead of  picture?

Comment: Do you mean a video?  In that case, something has gone horribly wrong and the system that is being created is so complex that it requires a video to fully understand what the problem actually is.  Also, the same thing with indexing and search engines apply; the audio of a video isn't indexed.

Comment: I cannot see how it could work.  Links to YT etc are already against the site policy and direct, permananet storage of mass video would greatly increase SO hosting costs.

Comment: Hmm, no, this kind of "sight" on ever makes fellow programmers with the same problem blind.  You are a programmer, you get paid to type.  Showing us what you typed is always best.

Comment: Petabytes of undebugged linked-lists generating segfaults...

Comment: I'd be down for that. Can we also add a special "sight" tag to those questions, so I know to add it to my ignored list? :)

Comment: well, it's just my suggestion. Thanks for all  your response :)

Comment: @Patrice:  What's even more mind-blowing is that absolutely none of the answers are invalidated with this revelation.

Comment: @PaulRoub What I meant is `sight` , like  wechat, which can provide a  video not more than 20 seconds, not `site`. Don't get me wrong dude...

Comment: ...And yet again, none of the answers are invalidated with *this* revelation either...

Comment: @Hoo Videos eeeeeeeek, cough, puke. No please! I see it as a severe problem that younger people more and more unlearn to read books and try to learn programming by watching videos. I don't know if it's because I'm an old fart, but I seriously believe it's not possible to achieve in depth information from videos.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm a young(er?) fart I guess, and I think the same. NOTHING can compare to my C/C++ bible, or my dragon book, when it comes to depth of information (and reusability)

Comment: @Patrice I can't actually tell, at which younger generation, that nonsensical behavior to rely on videos took place. Anyways each of a generation will have the smarter individuals, who would grasp what the right tools are for learning.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm not entirely sure it has ONLY to do with generation. I think studies help as well. A lot of self-taught coders seem to rely on videos, whereas most of the books I started with were mandatory for my Uni classes, which then helped me realize the power of these books.

Comment: @Patrice Since when we have YouTube available now? Sorry for my Alzheimer's tendencies ;-) ... I'm a self taught coder as well, I remember when I was 14 or so, I started to typewrite BASIC code into my VC20 computer from various magazines that were popular these days (not much better learning source as videos are nowadays).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ 2005, or so Google says. I was in Uni after that, so I guess I could've learned through video.... but then again, I've ALWAYS been a bookworm

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you mean, but it sounds like you are referring to either pictures of code or video. In both cases, these are problematic and should not be allowed, for several reasons:

- The contents of images and videos are not searchable (in Google, in this site's search, or anywhere else), which makes it impossible for users to find a post based on whatever is in the image or video.
- We can't copy and debug code that we see in an image or a video. In fact, the code formatting on Stack Overflow itself is often enough to highlight problems in the code, like missing quotation marks (`'` or `"`). That doesn't work with images or videos.
- As Makoto pointed out, the site requires that you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - code sufficient to reproduce the problem - in a question. An image or video doesn't help with that.
- Allowing this would *dramatically* increase the amount of spam and other nonsense that people would post here.

Good questions are questions that other users can understand. If we can't understand what you're asking, then (1) we can't help you, and (2) the question won't help others in the future. We need you, the person asking the question, to state the problem in a way that we can understand and that allows for an answer in no more than a few paragraphs. Images and video make this harder, not easier.

**Edit:** The question was edited after I wrote this, and now it sounds more like you want video, possibly even webcasting or screen-sharing features. Everything I said above still applies, with one more point: screen-sharing is not even reproducible or reusable unless it's saved to video, so it becomes useless immediately. Even when it's saved to a video and reused, it suffers from all of the problems above.

Comment: I'm not referring to either pictures of code or video. What I meant is `sight`,  like wechat, which can provide a video not more than 20 seconds ,so that we can easily to understand how the system actually run.

Comment: of course the user has to type their own code instead of giving a picture of code.

Comment: @Hoo Again, it's not clear what you mean by `sight`. It sounds like you *do* mean short videos, in which case all of my comments above apply. And if the user has to type code, explain the expected behavior, and state the specific error, then what good is a video to see "how the system actually runs?" The code and the error message already tell us that.

Comment: @hoo "I'm not referring to [...] video, what I mean is [...], which can provide a video".... WHAT?

Comment: @Patrice [...] WHAT?

Comment: @Hoo I'm quoting your comment and the [...] are irrelevant sections. You say in the same comment that you don't refer to video, but then you say "sight, like wechat, which can provide a video".... in the same message you say "video" and "NO video"... it's confusing

Comment: I'm sorry if I make you confused. English isn’t my first language, so please excuse any mistakes :) What I mean is I'm not referring to `video of code`.

Comment: @Hoo In that case, a video adds even less. A video of *what*? The user's development environment? If the answer depends on anything that the user would put in a video - like using an IDE - it almost certainly depends on something that should be in text, like the IDE settings. A video doesn't add anything here.

Comment: @Hoo no worries :) I'm happy to help clarify. Now that it is though, Ed's point is a very valid one

Comment: @Patrice you are right ^^

Answer (score 9):

Here's the problem with this idea:  what you get instead of questions with code and problems that are easily indexed by Google and straightforward to copy and paste into one's own IDE, are questions that are an amalgam of environmental and conceptual problems with no real hope for anyone outside of your head space to directly solve.

The big thing here is that this fails the requirement of an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) straight away.

If you cannot distill your question to one which replicates the problem in a very narrow situation, then you have not done your due diligence in researching and debugging the problem beforehand.  This makes it ***very*** difficult to offer any help.